# Make Xamarin.Uitest Tap Hamburger Icon in drawerlayout toolbar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uitest

I have a xamarin.uitestApp running in Visual Studio, I want to write tests for an App that uses the drawerlayout for navigation.

How do I make Xamarin.Uitest tap the Hamburger Icon in drawerlayout toolbar?

I have tried:

```
app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("toolbar"));
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("toolbar"));
```

The test succeeds, but the drawer is not opened.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, the menu button is drawn by the App and you can therefore assign an automationId to it either in XAML or in your app-code through the `AutomationId`-property.

In your test, you can then call it using `app.Tap("yourAutomationId")`

On Android, the button is drawn by the OS and therefore has a fixed automation id which you can't change. AFAIK, the id is always `OK` and you can therefore tap the button using

```
app.Tap("OK")
```

Comment: On android app.Tap("OK") simply worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the class to open the drawer

```
app.Tap(c => c.Class("OverflowMenuButton"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run repl check is there any id associated with your navigation drawer. If not you can use below query that I mentioned.

`app.Tap(x=>x.Class("NavigationDrawerClassNams"));`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty straight forward. Assign AutomationId to your burger menu view, whether this is in XAML or in code. Then you can tap on it with the same code you used, just replace  "toolbar" with whatever Name you gave to AutomationId.

Comment: Hi There, could you please tell me how to place the AutomationId on the  Burger menu view,

Comment: Same place where you put your BurgerMenu view. Whether its in xaml or code.